# Make Divs Absolute Only To Each Other

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, positioning, slideshow

I have `<div>` elements as pages, and "next" and "back" buttons to switch between them.  When the "next" button is clicked, the current page fades out and the next page fades in, using jQuery.  As I've been doing it so far, the only way to ensure that the divs sit on top of each other instead of sitting next to each other is to style them `position:absolute`.  However, this forces the divs to also overlay anything else on the page that they would otherwise push out of the way.

Is there any way to make divs basically positioned absolute only relative to each other, and still act as though they are positioned relative to the rest of the page?  I've tried putting them inside a container that is positioned relatively, but the divs overflow their container, making it more or less useless.

**Edit:**

Basic fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9AXS4/4/

Yes, I mix up `$` and `jQuery`.  I've been using jQuery a lot after calling `jQuery.noConflict()`

Comment: Can you show us a bit *more* of your code? Maybe as a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Could you also show a picture?

Comment: the only way is to use `position:relative;` overwise they don't keep their space in the dom

Comment: 'divs overflow their container' -> `overflow: hidden`

Comment: My html and javascript in my actual project is kinda jumbled and complicated, so I'm putting together a basic Fiddle now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your *pages*, as you call them, are of fixed width and height, then you can set their container to be `position:relative` and also have the width and height of the pages..

```
.container{
   position:relative;
   width:500px; /*the total width of a page, including padding and borders*/
   height:400px; /*the total height of a page, including padding and borders*/
}
```

This way the container element will handle the pushing around of the other elements

---

Here is your corrected fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/9AXS4/2/

(*the width/height of the container must account for paddings and border on the page elements*)
Also you were targeting the container with `.pagecontainer` instead of `#pagecontainer` (*since you used an `id`*)

---

**Update** (*after comment about arbitrary heights..*)

Since your pages height is not fixed, you will need to resort to jQuery to resize the container..

Here is a full demo : http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/9AXS4/7/

Comment: I've tried this implementation, and I guess I didn't really represent this very well in the fiddle but the height of the pages isn't actually fixed.  Better fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9AXS4/4/

And that id/class mixup was a typo

Comment: Awesome.  This is basically what I'm going to be using.

Answer (score 0):

The divs can't be positioned absolute in relation to each other, but they can be positioned absolutely in relation to an outer div. The container that holds the page divs should have `position: relative` in order to contain the inner page divs that are absolutely positioned.

If there is unwanted overlap, you can use `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` on the outer div to hide it, depending on whether or not you want to allow for scrolling. If you are going to use the `overflow` property, be sure to include a height and width so the browser knows where the overflow should be.

http://jsfiddle.net/vkTXs/

```
$(".page").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).hide();
});
$(".page").first().show();
$(".next").click(function() {
    jQuery(this)
    .parent().fadeOut()
    .next().fadeIn();
    var page = $(this).parent().next();
    resizeContainer(page);
});
$(".back").click(function() {
    jQuery(this)
    .parent().fadeOut()
    .prev().fadeIn();
    var page = $(this).parent().next();
    resizeContainer(page);
});

function resizeContainer(page){
    // get height of next page
    var newPageHeight = $(page).height();
    // add padding and border
    newPageHeight = newPageHeight + 14;
    $('#pagecontainer').height(newPageHeight);
}
```

Comment: This isn't really what I'm looking for.  I've already done this, and there is still overflow.  And I don't need the overflow to be hidden, I need it to change the size of the container accordingly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9AXS4/4/ is a more accurate implementation of what I'm trying to do.  My fault not putting it like that to start with.  The problem is I'm not actually fixing the height of the pages.

Comment: So, you want the view area size to change with the height of the pages?

Comment: I think that's about right.  Essentially at least emulating the styling of a normal relatively positioned element.